# Не появляется меню опций

Tags: android

Отсутствует меню на панели инструментов

MainActivity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainBottomNavigation"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainBottomNavigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottomnavigation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:title="@string/exit"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.class

```
@BindView(R.id.mainToolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_options_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.exit: 
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не вижу у Вас `ButterKnife.bind(this);`. И ещё значёк меню (три точки) может не появляться если у устройства есть аппаратная кнопка меню.

Comment: @woesss Аппаратная кнопка меню есть, по ее нажатии меню появляется, но сверху ее нет, до этого писал приложение, там меню появлялось, версия api тоже самое

Comment: В любом случае `bind` нужно добавить (после `setContentView`), иначе `toolbar` равен `null`, и метод `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` его не связывает с подсистемой активности.

Comment: @woesss Да и точно, я Butterknife добавил после setSupportActionBar(toolbar), поэтому была проблема, меню появилось. Добавьте ответ, чтобы отменить решением!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании библиотеки `ButterKnife` нужно вызывать метод связывания `ButterKnife.bind(...)` до обращения к виджетам, но после установки макета:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Тулбар же наделяется полноценным функционалом только после связывания его с активностью методом `setSupportActionBar(...)`.
В вашем случае поле `toolbar` не было инициализировано до вызова этого метода и тулбар просто отображался как обычный виджет, вроде кнопки или `TextView`, не выполняя своих функций.